# Start MongoDB without using sudo Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mongodb, sudo

I have setup and installed MongoDB on my Mac OS X. I currently can get it to run correctly with the following command

`sudo mongod`

Although, when I try to run the server with `mongod` command I get the following output

```
2015-05-06T09:51:19.436-0400 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=753 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=wificlient-10-201-122-48.uc.cl
2015-05-06T09:51:19.437-0400 [initandlisten] 
2015-05-06T09:51:19.437-0400 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
2015-05-06T09:51:19.437-0400 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.4
2015-05-06T09:51:19.437-0400 [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion
2015-05-06T09:51:19.437-0400 [initandlisten] build info: Darwin minimavericks.local 13.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.3.0: Tue Jun  3 21:27:35 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.110.17~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2015-05-06T09:51:19.437-0400 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2015-05-06T09:51:19.437-0400 [initandlisten] options: {}
2015-05-06T09:51:19.486-0400 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10309 Unable to create/open lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
2015-05-06T09:51:19.486-0400 [initandlisten] dbexit: 
2015-05-06T09:51:19.486-0400 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2015-05-06T09:51:19.486-0400 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2015-05-06T09:51:19.486-0400 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2015-05-06T09:51:19.486-0400 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2015-05-06T09:51:19.486-0400 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
2015-05-06T09:51:19.486-0400 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
2015-05-06T09:51:19.486-0400 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
2015-05-06T09:51:19.487-0400 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
2015-05-06T09:51:19.487-0400 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2015-05-06T09:51:19.487-0400 [initandlisten] couldn't remove fs lock errno:9 Bad file descriptor
2015-05-06T09:51:19.487-0400 [initandlisten] dbexit: really exiting now
```

BTW, I have not got another mongo instance running, I checked it with `sudo ps -ef | grep mongo`. How can I get MongoDB up and running without having to do it with the `sudo` command each time? I know that abusing `sudo` can bring possible future leaks.

Comment: Probably because after your initial invocation the files are now all owned by "root". If you delete them and run under your own user then this will be fine. Of course it is "recommended" to actually run under a "different" and "non-privileged" user account on **any** architecture.

Comment: And not to mention that "you already have an instance running". So without specifying another directory to start from then the "default" will just fail for using the same location and the same port to serve from

Comment: And "WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000" A process running as root can change those soft limits for itself, any other user can't.

Comment: @msw how can I change these soft limits?

Comment: The `ulimit -n` [command](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html) is the easiest way, but this is a lesser concern than others have pointed out.

Comment: @user3561036 How can I know where the files are so I can delete them, and also how can I specify another location? Thanks

Comment: @flizana The location and relevant command line option `--dbpath` are shown in the very first line of your output. See the [mongod](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongod/) command documentation

Comment: Thanks for your help, I just had to use a dbpath in my current working directory to solve problems.

Answer (score 0):

try using BREW for installing. you won't longer need to use sudo:
[Installing MongoDB](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.mongodb.org%2Fmanual%2Ftutorial%2Finstall-mongodb-on-os-x&ei=0SBiVZmpA4SXgwTVmYAQ&usg=AFQjCNFP7ltKqafX4pDPsBPNmUTjjicH2g&sig2=CSMRkagA-0jg3M9b1rDh8A&bvm=bv.93990622,d.eXY)

Or you can add `sudo mongod` into a default command